# Best way to handle sequential http requests with scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to make a series of requests, passing along data from one to the next then render all of the data to the jade view. Something like this

```
http.get(options, function(res) {  
    body='';
    res.on('data', function(d){
        body+=d;
        id=(JSON.parse(body)).id
        req2(id);
    });
});

function req2(id){
    options.path = '/example?id=' + id;
    http.get(options, function(res){
        body='';
        res.on('data', function(d){
            body+=d;
            name=(JSON.parse(body)).name;
            age=(JSON.parse(body)).age;
            req3(name, age);

        });

    });
}

function req3(name, age){
    options.path = '/example?name=' + name + '?age=' + age;
    http.get(options, function(res){
        body='';
        res.on('data', function(d){
            ....
        });
        res.on('end', function(){
            res.render('test', {id: id, name: name, age: age});
        })
    })
}
```

but this seems very slow and inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: usually you can use more named functions to cut down on repetition, like your POST collector for example, but also the whole callback in general. you want to bind() or pass the "next" sequence to a pure function; a callback for your callback. a formal way of doing that is Promises. for example, function req2(id, then) could accept req3 at calltime and use then(name, age) instead of req3(name, age).

Comment: I would use promises to chain a sequence of operations.  `operation1.then(operation2).then(operation3)`.